# multiple boards on single azure devops project

Tags: azure-boards

I have a project that I need to manage from end to end so that I track user stories from inception through to meeting the definition of ready and track that on a Kanban board.

I then want to have a backlog of items which meet the definition of ready from which I can sprint plan and then track these items from sprint backlog through development, test and finally to done using a scrum board.

I have looked through the organisation settings, but it seems that when you set the board process all boards use the same process.

is this possible in Azure DevOps?